# How to get app resume state on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe8

Is there something that can be checked from code point of view when an App is resumed on **iOS** and **Android**?

e.g. when an app gets minimized and restored (app is still running in background of device).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [IFMXApplicationEventService](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationEventService) to register a callback where the application will be notified:

```
uses FMX.Types, FMX.Platform;

function TForm1.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  case AAppEvent of
    TApplicationEvent.FinishedLaunching:    Log.d('Launched.');
    TApplicationEvent.BecameActive:         Log.d('Gained focus.');
    TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground:    Log.d('Now running in background.');
    TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground: Log.d('Restoring from background.');
    TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeInactive:   Log.d('Going to lose focus.');
    TApplicationEvent.WillTerminate:        Log.d('Quitting the application.');
    TApplicationEvent.LowMemory:            Log.d('Device running out of memory.');

    // iOS only
    TApplicationEvent.TimeChange:           Log.d('Significant change in time.');
    TApplicationEvent.OpenURL:              Log.d('Request to open an URL.');
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm11.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aFMXApplicationEventService: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService,
    IInterface(aFMXApplicationEventService))
  then
    aFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent)
  else
    Log.d('Application Event Service not supported.');
end;
```

More info about the event types [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Platform.TApplicationEvent).

A [good article](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/mobile-app-lifecycle-events-handling-in-delphi-xe5-40067) on the subject by *Paweł Głowacki* (for Delphi XE5, but still useful).

Answer (score 3):

In iOS You can add flag in

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

in appDelegate to know if the user enters the background and,

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

to know that the user returns to the app from background